# why does react update the state in this way

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm doing a quiz app with hooks and ran into a problem when I tried to update the answers array. Shortly put, I have 2 components - the first one is a start button which has a handler that renders the second component, the questions. In the questions component, there is a next button  whose handler updates the state with an object containing the question and the chosen answer like this:

```js
const newAnswers = [...answers, { q: data.question, a: selected }]
      onAnswerUpdate(newAnswers);
```

However, after the first click react just initiates the state with an empty array and returns it and after that lags behind with one object in the array ( in order to get the log of the question on which you clicked next you have to answer the next first). I tried to initiate the state in the start handler but it didn't work too.

Comment: Sounds like a case of stale data not coming from state, but you should include all of the relevant code. Maybe even a reproducible example in a sandbox.

Comment: Hi there please try coding your problem here
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-moon-xs3ry?file=/src/App.js